# Cog is loading but commands aren't working

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've been reading through the docs and previous Stack Overflow questions, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. **My cog loads fine on startup, but when I use the command with .8ball [Question] nothing happens, not even an error.** Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import random

class Fun(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name = "8ball")
    async def _8ball(ctx , * , question):
        startbool = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16 , 17 , 18 , 19 , 20 , 21]
        positiveResponses = ["It is certain." , "It is decidedly so." , "Without a doubt." , "Yes - definitely." , "You may rely on it." , "As I see it, yes." , "Most likely." , "Outlook good." , "Yes." ,
        "Signs point to yes."]
        negativeResponses = ["Don't count on it." , "My reply is no." , "My sources say no." , "Outlook not so good." , "Very doubtful."]

        result = random.choice(startbool)

        if result <= 10:
            embed = discord.Embed(colour = (discord.Colour.red()), title = 'Answer', description = f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(negativeResponses)}')

        if result >= 11:
            embed = discord.Embed(colour = (discord.Colour.green()), title = 'Answer', description = f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(positiveResponses)}')

        embed.set_thumbnail(url = "https://media4.giphy.com/media/l1IBiAKtFRpR9v9O8/giphy.gif")
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        member = ctx.message.author
        time = datetime.now()
        command = ctx.message.content
        print(f'{member} used {command} at {time}')



def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Fun(bot))
```

Comment: Do other commands work? Do you have a `on_message` defined? What have you tried to debug? More information will definitely make answering easier.

Comment: You''re missing self in the command arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this isn't working because for cogs you have to specify 'self' first since its inside of a class, here is what your code should look like
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import random

```
class Fun(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name = "8ball")
    async def 8ball(self, ctx , * , question):
        startbool = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16 , 17 , 18 , 19 , 20 , 21]
        positiveResponses = ["It is certain." , "It is decidedly so." , "Without a doubt." , "Yes - definitely." , "You may rely on it." , "As I see it, yes." , "Most likely." , "Outlook good." , "Yes." ,
        "Signs point to yes."]
        negativeResponses = ["Don't count on it." , "My reply is no." , "My sources say no." , "Outlook not so good." , "Very doubtful."]

        result = random.choice(startbool)

        if result <= 10:
            embed = discord.Embed(colour = (discord.Colour.red()), title = 'Answer', description = f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(negativeResponses)}')

        if result >= 11:
            embed = discord.Embed(colour = (discord.Colour.green()), title = 'Answer', description = f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(positiveResponses)}')

        embed.set_thumbnail(url = "https://media4.giphy.com/media/l1IBiAKtFRpR9v9O8/giphy.gif")
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        print(f'{ctx.message.author} used {ctx.message.content} at {datetime.now()}')



def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Fun(bot))
```

Comment: Ah didn't notice that, will look more closely in the future. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Vega no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As [Łukasz Kwieciński](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13131047/%C5%81ukasz-kwieci%C5%84ski) said, since you are inheriting from `commands.Cog` by creating a class, the method definition should contain `self` as first parameter (before ctx) just like in your `__init__` method. Here is the corrected method

```
@commands.command(name = "8ball")
async def _8ball(self, ctx , * , question):
    startbool = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16 , 17 , 18 , 19 , 20 , 21]
    positiveResponses = ["It is certain." , "It is decidedly so." , "Without a doubt." , "Yes - definitely." , "You may rely on it." , "As I see it, yes." , "Most likely." , "Outlook good." , "Yes." ,
    "Signs point to yes."]
    negativeResponses = ["Don't count on it." , "My reply is no." , "My sources say no." , "Outlook not so good." , "Very doubtful."]

    result = random.choice(startbool)

    if result <= 10:
        embed = discord.Embed(colour = (discord.Colour.red()), title = 'Answer', description = f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(negativeResponses)}')

    if result >= 11:
        embed = discord.Embed(colour = (discord.Colour.green()), title = 'Answer', description = f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(positiveResponses)}')

    embed.set_thumbnail(url = "https://media4.giphy.com/media/l1IBiAKtFRpR9v9O8/giphy.gif")
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    member = ctx.message.author
    time = datetime.now()
    command = ctx.message.content
    print(f'{member} used {command} at {time}')
```